# Laravel bootstrap.js pass a flash message

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2

I use this flash package: https://github.com/keen-on-design/vue-flash-message

I need to call the flash function in my bootstrap.js.

I tried do this:

```
window.events = new Vue();

window.events.flash('There are error, 'error');
```

But this doesn't work. Why? On app.js all is good.

Comment: Can you please provide details of the errors you're getting? Thanks

Comment: @danboh I don't get errors.. When I call 500 error, flash method is not working. If I write console.log() then all working